# Topshelf passing username and password to the configuration

Tags: installation, topshelf

One thing i am struggling with is registering a service with a user name and password.

i can hard code the user name and password to the RunAs method and register the service but obviously not practical.

if i

```
myservice.exe install start -username:Domain\username -password:itsAsecret
```

or

```
myservice.exe install start -username "Domain\username" -password "itsAsecret"
```

the service registers and starts running under the the local system.

how do i pass the username and password to the:

```
configure.RunAs(username, password)
```

method?

to get around this i have parsed the commanline my self
and then i can :

```
if (commandlineParameters.ContainsKey("username") && commandlineParameters.ContainsKey("password"))
    configure.RunAs(commandlineParameters["username"], commandlineParameters["password"]); 
else
    configure.RunAsLocalSystem();
```

but i feel this should work:

```
 configure.ApplyCommandLine(string.Join(" ", args));
```

or simply

```
 configure.ApplyCommandLine();
```

But when i do the service is registered as Local system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems the problem was the command "start" with the installation.

so, to install and start the service it will need to be two separate commands.

```
myservice.exe install -username:Domain\username -password:itsAsecret
myservice.exe start
```

This means i can get rid of the parsing code i added and simply

```
configure.ApplyCommandLine();
```